# Missing top and bottom border in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem with border in IE7.  For some reason the border shows only from the left and the right side:

IE7, renders incorectly:

[image]

FF, renders correctly:

[image]

Using this CSS:

```
.tags a {
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #D8DFEA;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  color:#3B5998;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the borders are clipped by the height of the `.tags` container. The css for `.tags a` itself looks OK.

Note that since `<a>` is an inline element you can't set it's height (unless you set it to `display:block`). The height difference is most likely caused by the fonts being rendered differently by different browsers. Also watch out for Safari which tends to render fonts fatter (taking up more pixels) than all other browsers.

Comment: what should I do in that case ?

Comment: Show us the css rule of `.tags` or any other parent container where height is set. The css you're showing us does not cause the bug.

Comment: Excellent champ, when I set it to display block they went in seperate lines, I added float left , now it works tnx

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem in IE. I think this was cause by me setting the font-size within this div.

I set the line-height to match my font-size, and this works in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari - yeah!

Comment: line-height fixed the problem that was happening in ie9 too!

Answer (score 0):

Helena's solution worked for me too, but to clarify, I had to set the `line-height` of the surrounding `<div>` to be a slightly bigger than the font size of the `<a>`.

So something like this:

```
<div style="line-height:40px">
    <a style="font: 14px/36px Arial; ....">
</div>
```